# Python returns NoneType if an Except happens in recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, exception

I am scraping from a site using Requests. Given a valid URL, I loop through API services and available tables inside those services. The target site is old and will throw 500 codes at random, so I must control for this.

At present, I feed a For loop a list of Services. The loop sends services to a function that generates a URL to query the site for the names of Tables, and builds a dictionary of table names and ID's.

To catch the 500 codes and immediately retry the query, I use a try/except block inside the function, and direct the function to a separate helper function that prints a helpful error message stating that it got a 500 code. The helper then calls the function again, passing the query back to it, and it tries again.

The function works as expected when no 500 code is received. The function returns a dictionary for me with my IDs and names.

However, if a 500 code is received for that query, the function retries the query as described above, and is successful. However, the function returns None in these cases.

```py
def sit_and_wait(url):
    print("500 received. sleeping.")
    time.sleep(1)
    query_for_tables(url)

def query_for_tables(url):
    data = r.get(url)
    content = json.loads(data)
    please_return_this_dict = {}
    try:
        if content['tables']:
            for x in content['tables']:
                please_return_this_dict[x['id']] = x['name']
            return please_return_this_dict
            print(please_return_this_dict) # always prints the dict
    except KeyError:
        # the API returned a JSON string like "'error':'500'"
        sit_and_wait(url)

my_tables = query_for_tables(url)
print(type(my_tables)) 
# If a 500 status was received at least once, this returns NoneType
```

If the Except is never hit and sit_and_wait is unused in the function, the dictionary returns as expected. If the website gives me a 500 code any nonzero number of times, I receive a NoneType return.

Comment: What else did you expect it to return? There is no return statement, so it will implicitly return `None`.

Comment: As an aside, please tag all python related questions with the generic [python] tag

Comment: Also, it's better to use a loop than recursion for stuff like this. I've added a dupe target for retry code, although there's probably a closer match somewhere. The dupe target I used is for user input, but most of the same techniques and considerations apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that once it does not get a 500, it will return a value to `sit_and_wait` but `sit_and_wait` does not return that value back to `query_for_tables`.  This will result in no return, or `None` being returned back to the initial `query_for_tables` in the `except` which will return `None`.

```
def sit_and_wait(url):
    print("500 received. sleeping.")
    time.sleep(1)
    return query_for_tables(url)

def query_for_tables(url):
    data = r.get(url)
    content = json.loads(data)
    please_return_this_dict = {}
    try:
        if content['tables']:
            for x in content['tables']:
                please_return_this_dict[x['id']] = x['name']
            return please_return_this_dict
            print(please_return_this_dict) # always prints the dict
    except KeyError:
        # the API returned a JSON string like "'error':'500'"
        return sit_and_wait(url)

my_tables = query_for_tables(url)
print(type(my_tables))
```

This would be an example with a loop, which in most cases is better.

```
def query_for_tables(url):
    data = r.get(url)
    content = json.loads(data)
    please_return_this_dict = {}
    for i in range(100): # 100 second timeout
        try:
            if content['tables']:
                for x in content['tables']:
                    please_return_this_dict[x['id']] = x['name']
                return please_return_this_dict
                print(please_return_this_dict) # always prints the dict
        except KeyError:
            print("500 received. sleeping.")
            time.sleep(1)

my_tables = query_for_tables(url)
print(type(my_tables))
```

Comment: Thank you. The "duplicate" questions didn't turn up in any searches for me and I now understand the importance of passing to other functions by returning.

Comment: No problem.  As the comments said though, it would be better to put a loop in there instead of doing this nested call.  This can actually be problematic for many reasons.  If it never detects a non error, it will loop forever.  A loop with a certain time limit will be more beneficial.  In addition, if you want this to loop for a while, this will be very nested.  For instance, if `sit_and_wait` is called 1000 times, there will be 1000 return statements that will be executed after query_for_tables finally succeeds.